# VPN connection for specific app on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vpn

I wonder if there's the possibility in Windows 8 to use its built-in VPN client to set up a connection just for specified applications, so that not the whole traffic is tunneled.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Its possible but it requires a third-party VPN client that supports doing it.  The built-in VPN client does not have this feature.